# Passing raw RTMP video data to FFmpeg

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to implement a simple RTMP client in Node.js using TCP sockets and FFmpeg. Until now I have implemented the connection to a stream, after which the server starts sending video and audio data messages. According to Wireshark the first byte of such messages contains information related to the type of frame and data encoding (codecs), in my client app video data is in "Sorensen H.263" format.

When I use ffplay to play the stream, it logs the video data is in FLV format, but when passing the packets payload data to ffmpeg using this format I always get this error:

`pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input`

What parameters should I provide to ffmpeg when piping RTMP video data to get proper video output in any desired format?

Comment: What's the ffmpeg command being executed?

Comment: Since I get the video data from the socket I used `ffmpeg -i - -f flv output.mp4`